# What git commands will allow me to checkout only the files that would be modified by a git pull?

Tags: git

Let's say I've edited 50 files in a repository, and now it won't allow me to git pull because of all of my local changes. Is there a command, or series of commands I can use to allow the git pull to overwrite any locally changed file that it needs to, while keeping the rest unchanged?

Git stash will remove too many of my local changes, and using git checkout for that many files would be incredibly tedious.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect time to use `git rebase` https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing - this will do exactly what you want and merge your stuff together.. it may give you some merge conflicts but you can handle them easily again in git.

```
 git fetch
 git rebase origin/{yourbranch}
```

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is the same as `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

The reason Git is not allowing you to do this is because you have *uncommitted* changes. Commit these first, then try again.

---

On a related note, instead of merging upstream into your local branch (which would happen if you simply did `git pull`), it is mostly a good idea to rebase instead. It is handy to work on a separate branch and rebase that from time to time:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

Then:

```
# (work work work)
git add <stuff>
git commit
# (others add unrelated changes in the branch you branched off of)
git fetch
git rebase origin/master  # (for example)
# (loop)
```

When done you can simply merge your branch back.

```
git checkout master        # (for example)
git pull
git merge --no-ff feature  # (--no-ff is optional)
```

---

If you insist on working on a branch that other people are adding new changes to without creating your own feature branch, you can use the `--rebase` option to `git pull` to have it rebase instead of creating an unnecessary merge commit.

More info at [man git-pull](https://gitirc.eu/git-pull.html), [man git-fetch](https://gitirc.eu/git-fetch.html), [man git-merge](https://gitirc.eu/git-merge.html).

Answer (score 0):

`git stash` is a good solution. Than you should do:

```
git pull origin someBranch
git stash pop
```

then resolve possible conflicts (for example "resolve using mine").

```
git checkout --ours -- file/with/conflict/to/resolve
```